# ¿Cómo obtener los géneros de una lista en Python?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, diccionarios

Tengo un dataset de peliculas con distintas caracteristicas (recaudación, presupuesto, popularidad, generos...).

Quiero calcular la predicción en taquilla que va a tener un conjunto de test.

Entonces quiero analizar las variables categóricas, en este caso el género. Cuando leo la columna del género obtengo un string de este tipo:

```
"[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]"
```

Lo que quiero hacer es algo similar al OneHotEncoding, es decir, convertir cada género distinto en una columna y luego rellenar con 1s y 0s en función de si pertenece a ese género o no.

No quiero que cada celda se me convierta en una nueva columna, o sea, quiero los géneros separados individualmente. Por ejemplo, si una película es de genero comedia-drama, se cree una columna con ambos géneros.

Por eso, y como me llevo comiendo la cabeza mucho tiempo y no consigo sacarlo os pido ayuda. De momento sólo para coger los géneros del string que he escrito antes. Y una vez con eso ya puedo seguir por mi cuenta.

Comment: Para mejor entender tu pregunta, tienes que mostrar el resultado que buscas (igual como muestras la lista de géneros). También el código que has escrito hasta el momento.

Comment: Aunque primero tendrás que reemplazar las comillas simples por dobles (text.replace("\'", "\""), puedes convertir tu texto en una lista de diccionarios con json.loads(texto)

Answer (score 1):

Voy a tratar de mejorar la respuesta...

Según entiendo buscas OneHotEncoding, es decir, columnas de 1s y 0s que te indican si in id pertenece o no a un genero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necestiaremos paquetes pandas y json

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
```

(1) Input: Tenemos un string, vamos a guardarlo como lista, siguiendo las indicaciones de [Adrián Sanz Wallace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/137306/adri%C3%A1n-sanz-wallace)

```py
#tomamos el string y convertimos a lista
text = "[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 
10751, 'name': 'Family'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]"
text = text.replace("\'", "\"")
list_films = json.loads(text)
```

(2)Para trabajar con los elementos vamos a pasar a Dataframe, luego identificamos los posibles géneros con el método unique() sobre el campo films.name que en tu caso es el genero del id correspondiente a una película

```py
films = pd.DataFrame(list_films)
#listado de posibles generos con método unique() 
genres = films.name.unique()
```

(3) Filtrado de los id en los que se cumple la condicion genero = comedy

```py
#listado en columna de genero comedy
comedy = [0] * len(films.id)
tmp = films
tmp[(tmp.name != genres[0])] = 0
tmp[(tmp.name == genres[0])] = 1
comedy = list(tmp.name)
```

En la lista resultante tienes en lista que ids pertenecen al genero comedy indicado con 1s
Ids
[35, 18, 10751, 10749]
Comedy
[1,   0,     0,     0]

solo te faltaría hacer de forma recursiva para el resto de categorias.

Comment: no entiendo cuando te votan en negativo sin dar ninguna explicación o motivo... estoy aquí para aprender y creo que mi ejemplo cumple con lo que se ha solicitado. Seguro que hay mejores y mas eficiente formas de hacerlo y puede que lo que hago este mal, pero al menos un comentario indicando a que se motiva ese voto negativo.

Comment: Yo no te vote, pero respuestas como ésta aportan poco. Quizás le solucionan el problema al OP, pero no le han enseñado nada, y queda tan ignorante y desvalido como al principio. Una buena respuesta: 1) Identifica y explica el problema; 2) Provee una solución y la explica, de modo que quien la lea **aprenda** y no vuelva a caer en el mismo problema. Si editas tu pregunta y provees las explicaciones que faltan, ganaras puntos. En caso contrario, terminara cerrada, por la simple razón de que no le es útil a nadie más que al OP.

Comment: Editar y ampliar está misma respuesta para empezar

Answer (score 0):

### Datos de partida

Comencemos por crear un dataset con unas pocas filas que puedan ilustrar el problema:

```
import pandas as pd

pelis = [
         {"title": "Flying Circus", "genre": "[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]"},
         {"title": "A fish called Wanda", "genre": "[{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]"},
         {"title": "Brazil", "genre": "[{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'},  {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]"}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(pelis)
```

Estos son sus datos:

```
                 title                                              genre
0        Flying Circus  [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, '...
1  A fish called Wanda  [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, ...
2               Brazil  [{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'},  {'id': 35, 'nam...
```

La columna "genre" es en realidad una cadena, aunque pueda parecer una lista. Esa cadena no es JSON válido, pues las comillas son simples en vez de dobles, pero la sintaxis es la de una lista de diccionarios python que podemos recuperar haciendo `eval()` sobre dicha cadena.

### Extracción de información de la columna "genre"

Así pues, para extraer lo que serían únicamente los nombres de los géneros podríamos tener una función que reciba una de esas cadenas y haga lo siguiente:

```
def string_to_genres_list(x):
  d = eval(x)
  return [c["name"] for c in d]
```

Podemos aplicar esta función a nuestro dataframe para crear una nueva columna que llamaré "generos" cuyos elementos serán listas de nombres:

```
df["generos"] = df.genre.apply(string_to_genres_list)
```

Ahora el dataframe df tiene una nueva columna:

```
                 title  ...            generos
0        Flying Circus  ...   [Comedy, Family]
1  A fish called Wanda  ...  [Romance, Comedy]
2               Brazil  ...    [Drama, Comedy]
```

### ¿Cómo encontrar la lista de géneros "global"?

Vemos que aunque cada fila presente solo un par de géneros, el número total de ellos es cuatro. Necesitaríamos hacer la "unión" de todas las listas que hay en toda esa columna, para obtener una lista única con todos los nombres de género encontrados, y sin duplicados, de modo que podamos usar esa lista para añadir columnas nuevas, una por género.

Usando conjuntos python es sencillo obtener esa lista (pues los conjuntos eliminan duplicados):

```
generos_hallados = sorted(list(set().union(*df.generos)))
```

El truco es crear un `set()` vacío y aplicar en él la operación `union()` pasándole como parámetros los valores de la columna `generos`. El conjunto resultante se convierte de nuevo en lista, y finalmente la ordeno alfabéticamente (esto no era necesario, pero ya puestos...) Y el resultado en este caso es:

```
['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Family', 'Romance']
```

### Añadiendo columnas nuevas a df

Esto ya nos permite crear columnas adicionales en df, que rellenaré provisionalmente con ceros. La siguiente (única) línea crea las columnas adicionales y las rellena con ceros:

```
df[generos_hallados] = 0
```

Ahora mismo el dataframe está así:

```
                 title                genre            generos  Comedy  Drama  Family  Romance
0        Flying Circus  [{'id': 35, 'nam...   [Comedy, Family]       0      0       0        0
1  A fish called Wanda  [{'id': 10749, '...  [Romance, Comedy]       0      0       0        0
2               Brazil  [{'id': 18, 'nam...    [Drama, Comedy]       0      0       0        0
```

### Poner los 1s

Ya sólo queda sustituir esos ceros por unos donde corresponda, lo que se puede hacer aplicando una función a cada fila. Esta función recibirá como parámetro una fila con sus valores originales, y devolverá la fila con los nuevos valores que debe tener.

```
def rellenar_unos(fila):
  for genero in fila.generos:
    fila[genero] = 1
  return fila.drop(["genre", "generos"])
```

Como ves, basta iterar por lo que la fila tenga en su columna `.generos` para ir poniendo un 1 en las columnas apropiadas. Después se retorna la fila modificada. Observa cómo aprovecho para eliminar de esa fila las columnas "genre" y "generos" que ya no nos son necesarias.

Aplicar esta función a cada fila se hace así:

```
df = df.apply(rellenar_unos, axis=1)
```

Y por fin llegamos al dataframe final:

```
                 title  Comedy  Drama  Family  Romance
0        Flying Circus       1      0       1        0
1  A fish called Wanda       1      0       0        1
2               Brazil       1      1       0        0
```